# When i scroll down in file js or vue on neovim, the colorscheme change to white

Tags: vue.js, neovim

when i scroll down in file js or vue on neovim, the colorscheme change to white
i don't know the problem.
https://i.postimg.cc/W10YqxXg/Grabaci-n-de-pantalla-desde-13-05-22-16-12-13-min.gif

Comment: did you ever figure this issue out?

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier to figure out your issue if you provided your config in the question.

I'm guessing you are using `nvim-treesitter` for highlights,
And the plugin is still in beta state and sometimes syntax highlights can be broken.
Especially on a large files and codes with embedded code in other language.

You can fix this temporarily by either restarting Neovim,
or running `:write | edit | TSBufEnable highlight` to force reload.

[source](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter#i-experience-weird-highlighting-issues-similar-to-78)